# Strange error when inserting javascript in a haml underscore template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, haml, underscore.js

Getting a strange error when insurting javascript in a haml underscore template

This works perfect:

```
.button{ :id => "<%= 'class_name' %>" }
```

This one gives an error

```
.button{ :class => "<%= 'class_name' %>" }
```

The only difference is that i use class instead of id....

The javascript error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

UPDATE:

<%= %> comes from underscore template engine. So it is not erb or any kind of thing. I dont get a error while generating haml but i get it with javascript.

Comment: The javascript returns correctly the `class_name`? Because add classes is possible in [HAML](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peLva)

Comment: Looks like you forgot that `<%= ... %>` comes from ERb, not from Haml.

Comment: <%= %> isnt erb here but for underscore template.

Comment: 'class_name' is just a test string that i use to replicate the error im getting.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/haml/eYSx8rtk5E0

Comment: Thanks shioyama. I can indeed solve it by that. I just solved it to delete the spaces. Guess class behaves differently than id. If you put that comment in an answer i accept it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `.button{ :id => "<%= 'class_name' %>" }` is working, I’m assuming you have `:escape_attrs` set to false, and possibly `:attr_wrapper` set to `"`, which would produce the output:

```html
<div class="button" id="<%= 'class_name' %>"></div>
```

The bit that is causing you trouble, `.button{ :class => "<%= 'class_name' %>" }`, will produce:

```html
<div class="%> 'class_name' <%= button"></div>
```

The problem is caused when Haml combines the `class` elements from the `.` syntax (`button`) with the contents of the class entry of the attribute hash (`<%= 'class_name' %>`). Haml treats the latter as a space separated list, adds the `button` element, and then sorts the resulting array, producing the output you see. (Treating the list as a space separated list like this makes sense for “pure” HTML, but breaks down when javascript frameworks use it in this way. The reason for sorting was to provide a consistent order of class entries for Haml’s test suite.)

A workaround is to not use the `.` syntax and a `:class` entry in the attributes hash together – just use the `class` entry:

```haml
%div{ :class => "button <%= 'class_name' %>" }
```

produces:

```html
<div class="button <%= 'class_name' %>"></div>
```

Another workaround (that you’ve already discovered) is to remove the spaces from the underscore template, so Haml treats it as a single entity and doesn’t split it up.

Comment: A lean solution to a frequent problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
.button{:class => "#{class_name}"}
```

Comment: Overcomplicated! `.button{ :class => class_name }` is enough - no need to use a string with interpolation.

Comment: This isnt a ruby/haml error but a javascript error. I use underscore template engine.